# Unable to make the table header and search box fixed inside the table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my table header row and the search filter input above the 
table header to fixed(which should be non scrollable). But I am unable to do so. I tried many ways like putting the `thead position:fixed`. But none worked. Could anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.
Below is my html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar"
     style="margin: 5%; border-radius: 10px; border-style: groove;">

  <input id="searchField"
         type="text" [(ngModel)]="term"
         class="form-group " placeholder="Search" />

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Col1</th>
      <th scope="col">Col2</th>
      <th scope="col">Col3</th>
      <th scope="col">Col4</th>
      <th scope="col">Col5</th>
      <th scope="col">Col6</th>
      <th scope="col">Col7</th>
      <th scope="col">Col8</th>
      <th scope="col">Col9</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
   .my-custom-scrollbar {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  .table-wrapper-scroll-y {
    display: block;
  }

  #searchField {

    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    border-color: #6b645c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left-color: #6b645c;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
  }

  .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
    display: block;
  }
```

My solution 
https://jsfiddle.net/timeoutexception/1s75qpcj/1/

Answer (score 1):

May be `position: sticky;` is something which you need to use to make the search box stay on top while the `table` is scrolled.

```css
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}

#searchField {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  border-color: #6b645c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-left-color: #6b645c;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar" style="margin: 5%; border-radius: 10px; border-style: groove;">

  <input id="searchField" type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" class="form-group " placeholder="Search" />

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Col1</th>
        <th scope="col">Col2</th>
        <th scope="col">Col3</th>
        <th scope="col">Col4</th>
        <th scope="col">Col5</th>
        <th scope="col">Col6</th>
        <th scope="col">Col7</th>
        <th scope="col">Col8</th>
        <th scope="col">Col9</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```